# Get post thumbnail from subpages with a foreach loop

Tags: post-thumbnails, php

I have created a page that loads content from it's subpages.
The subpages contain `post_thubnails`.
I use a `foreach`-loop to get the content of all pages.
I just can't get the images loaded.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'asc',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'child_of' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    ); 
    $pages = get_pages($args); 
    foreach ($pages as $page){
        $file = get_post_meta ( $page->ID, '_wp_attached_file', true );
        echo $file;
        echo '
        <div class="full_width_parallax">
        <div class="wrap_1280">';
        echo $page->post_content;   
    echo '</div>    
    </div>';

    }

?>
```

Aside from the example code I have also tried `the_post_thumbnail();` but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may also want to run your content through `apply_filters( 'the_content', $page->post_content );` which will add paragraph tags and such to your post content where necessary.

Comment: Thnx that helped!

Answer (score 2):

Life can be simple:

Instead of `the_post_thumbnail` I should use `get_the_post_thumbnail`

`echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID)`